# Flutter - iOS Textfield can not delete after pop()

Tags: ios, flutter, textfield, backspace

I have a Textfield at the [Forgot_password] screen to enter the phone number and push to the [OTP_verifying] screen. But when I pop() back to the [Forgot_password] screen the delete/backspace button on IOS doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
Widget _buildForm() {
String phoneNumberHintText =
    _localizationService.auth__login__phone_number_label;
return Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _phoneNumberController,
          validator: _validatePhoneNumber,
          autocorrect: false,
          autofocus: true,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          onChanged: _onChange,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]),
);}

void _submitForm() async {
_isSubmitted = true;
_setIsLoading(true);
if (_validateForm()) {
  try {
   // Some logic code
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/auth/verify_phone_step',
        arguments: {'phoneNumber': _phoneNumberController.text});
}
_setIsLoading(false);}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some code of what you implemented.

Comment: I just added my code to the post. Please have a look. @DineshNagarajan

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution which is we can unfocus the Textfield after pop from OTP verifying screen to prevent this issue.

```
void _submitForm() async {
_isSubmitted = true;
_setIsLoading(true);
if (_validateForm()) {
  try {
    // Some logic code
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/auth/verify_phone_step',
        arguments: {'phoneNumber': _phoneNumberController.text});
  } finally {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  }
}
_setIsLoading(false);}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you push in OTP_verifying screen from Forgot_password screen you can add this code:

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/auth/verify_phone_step',
    arguments: {'phoneNumber': _phoneNumberController.text});
_phoneNumberController.clear();
```